# Is there a way to determine the real mac address of a host that is using a randomized address on a wireless network?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ip, mac-address

I want to find the real mac address of a host that is using mac randomization. Is there a tool that can help me discover its real mac address?

Things I've tried:

- Modifying my system's arp table and using arping to bruteforce search for the host (I know the manufacturer of the wireless card and thus the first three bytes of the hidden MAC address), but that didn't work when I tested it on my machine. Probably wireless cards don't respond when configured with a different mac address, or maybe the access point drops the packet. I don't know.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.

Even if randomized or manually changed, the MAC address that a system is currently using **becomes** its "real" address for the duration. That is, the new address isn't "emulated", but fully replaces the original MAC address in both the OS and the wireless adapter's firmware (in RAM) – the WLAN firmware no longer uses the original address for any purpose and the OS network stack no longer recognizes the original address as belonging to the local system.

(The only difference between is that the randomization procedure doesn't reprogram the wireless interface's EEPROM, so the new address stays temporary and would be reset after a power cycle, while the "real" address is re-read from EEPROM every time.)

Comment: and, I mean, that's kind of *the whole point* of MAC address randomization, isn't it?

Comment: Additional consideration is that wireless station *authenticates* to the access point using its current MAC, and the AP *will not* let any packets from client if the source MAC is not the MAC that has been authenticated. There is simply no place for additional "client" MACs in 802.11 protocols.

Comment: So I take it the `permaddr` entry in the output of `ip addr` is just there for informative purposes and is not used once the randomized mac address is set?